# Cannot authorize via Twitter TwitterAuthClient authorize null result

Tags: java, android, authentication, twitter

I can't sign in via Twitter or get any data from my account using Fabric and Twitter SDK. 
My code:

```
twitterAuthClient.authorize(LoginActivity.this, new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                Log.d("LoginActivity", "Twitter login success");
                TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException e) {
                Log.d("LoginActivity", e.getMessage());
                Helpers.showToast(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage());
            }
        });
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    twitterAuthClient.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult:" + requestCode + ":" + resultCode + ":" + data);
    }
}
```

I configured it by Fabric.io, added key and secret to fabric.properties, granted access to my Twitter account and userName and authToken from callback are null. What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Ok I solved it. The problem was there was no added Access Token on Twitter app. If you see this kind of result - login to http://dev.twitter.com/apps and add the Access Token.